# angularjs scope bindings and rootscope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have some elements I want to only show the author of the document.

I can do something like this:

```
<div ui-show="currentUser == doc.user">Edit</div>
<div ui-show="currentUser == doc.user">Review</div>
```

Which is fine but because in my production code the ui-show is much longer than this example I don't want to copy and paste it everywhere that I need it.

I want to set a single variable that'll dynamically update as users log in and out or as the document gets updated with new / different users.

```
<div ui-show="isUser">Edit</div>
<div ui-show="isUser">Review</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I could make isUser into a function.

```
<div ui-show="isUser()">Edit</div>
<div ui-show="isUser()">Review</div>
```

And write the conditions in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options to solve this problem:

1)  Introduce a "global" or "parent" controller to your application.  This will contain your `isUser` scope variable that you can basically set from any controller beneath this controller.  Meaning that you can have a `LogInController` which will handle log off/in and can set that variable via `$scope.isUser = false`.

Here is a fiddle with an example of what this might look like: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalzebra/MrQrX/

2) Load different templates or includes based on whether or not the user is logged in/off.  when using `<ng-include src="partialTemplate">` the `src` attribute is actually an expression.  So, you can toggle what template is actually loaded based on the value of that expression.  You can then set the value in your controller and dynamically change which template is loaded: `$scope.partialTemplate = "loggedOff.html"`